# Script length limitation on DTrace Java API?

Tags: java, dtrace

I have a Java program that uses the Java DTrace API ([Java DTrace API](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/819-2183/auto9/index.html)) to build and execute a dtrace script on Solaris Sparc 10. The script uses the pid provider to place probes on the entry points of all the functions in a set of libraries, like this (in reality there are over 100 libraries so the script is quite long):

```
pid1234:liba::entry,pid1234:libb::entry,pid1234:libc::entry {printf("%s", probemod);}
```

My code looks like:

```
_consumer = new LocalConsumer();
_consumer.open(); 
// set the zdefs option to allow scripts with no probes
_consumer.setOption(org.opensolaris.os.dtrace.Option.zdefs);            
_consumer.compile(_dtraceScript); // where _dtraceScript is a string as described above
```

The call to compile fails with:

```
invalid probe specifier pid1234:liba::entry,pid1234:libb::entry...[truncated]
```

I have copied and pasted the script in it's entirety and executed it at the command line using:

```
dtrace -n '...my script...'
```

... and it works fine, so I know there is nothing syntactically wrong with my script.

So, two problems/questions:

1. Why is the compilation failing? Since the script runs on the command line, but not via Java, am I hitting some limitation of the Java DTrace API, like script length? Or maybe the JVM is running out of memory because I'm trying to enable so many probes?
2. Since the exception message is truncated (because my script is so long)  how can I see the dtrace error that usually appears at the end of the exception message?

Any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: What OS are you running on?

Comment: Sorry for leaving that out - I updated the question - it's Solaris Sparc 10.  Thanks Andrew.